# How many four-digit even numbers with no repeating digits satisfy the inequality $1000 \leq N < 6000$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

The question at hand is asking for four-digit even numbers with no repeating digits within a certain bounds, such as $1000 \le N < 6000$.

$$N = (n_1)(n_2)(n_3)(n_4)$$

$$n_1 = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

$$n_2 = \{0,1,...,9\}$$

$$n_3 = \{0,1,...,9\}$$

$$n_4 = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$$

Suppose $n_4=0$, then the sum is $5 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 5$.

Suppose $n_4=2$, then $4 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 5$

so the "value" of $n_1$ varies with $n_4=\{2,4\}$...

How do I take this variation into account when producing the final answer?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Please check your work.  If the units digit is $0$, you only have one choice for the units digit.  This is true when the units digit is $2$.  You could consider cases depending on the units digit.  However, you will obtain the same result if the units digit is $2$ or $4$ and will obtain the same result if the units digit is $6$ or $8$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You do them separately and add the results.

Comment: If $n =0$ then only have *one* choice for $n_4$.  If $n_4=0,6$ or $8$ you have three choices for $n_4$ so $5*8*7*3$ and if $n_4=2,4$ you have two choices for $n_4$ so $4*8*7*2$.  So the final answer is $5*8*7*3 + 4*8*7*2$.

Answer (score 1):

There $5$ options for $n_4$.  Two of the choices are $2,4$ and three of them are $0,6,8$.

$n_1$ may be $1,2,3,4$ or $5$.  If choices $2$ or $4$ for $n_4$ there are $4$ remaining options for $n_1$.  So there are $2*4$ options for $n_1, n_4$ if $n_4 = 2,4$.  Otherwise there are $5$ options for $n_1$ if $n_4= 0,6,8$.  So there are $3*5$ options for $n_1, n_4$ if $n_4 =0,6,8$.

So there are $2*4 + 3*5$ options for $n_1$ and $n_4$.

$n_2$ may be any of the $10$ digits other than $n_1, n_4$ so there are 8 options.  And $n_3$ may be any other than $n_1,n_4,n_2$ so there are 7 options.

So there are $(2*4 + 3*5)*8*7$ such numbers.